# Loop through all charts in a workbook with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, charts, foreach

I am trying to loop through all charts in a workbook.
Why is option 1 working, but option 2 not?

'OPTION 1

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
        MsgBox (cht.Name)
    Next cht
Next sht
```

'OPTION2

```
Dim oChart As Chart
    For Each oChart In Application.Charts
        MsgBox (oChart.Name)
    Next oChart
End Sub
```

Comment: option 1 lists all _embedded charts_ (i.e. charts that are contained in any worksheet - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195149(v=office.15).aspx)), while option 2 lists all _chart sheets_ (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839597(v=office.15).aspx))

Answer (score 17):

There are two flavors of charts:

1. "big" charts - an entire chart sheet
2. "little" charts - chart objects embedded in a worksheet

This code:

```vb
Sub dural()
    Dim oChart As Chart
    For Each oChart In Application.Charts
        MsgBox oChart.Parent.Name & vbCrLf & oChart.Name
    Next oChart
End Sub
```

will display information about the "big" variety.

and if you want information on the "little" charts:

```vb
Sub dural2()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To sh.ChartObjects.Count
                MsgBox sh.ChartObjects(i).Chart.Name
            Next i
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Note that we need an explicit `If` statement to handle sheets with no charts and `.Chart` is used to access the Chart within each of the ChartObjects list.

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839597.aspx), `Application.Charts` returns a `Sheets` collection containg all chart sheets (not charts!). For `Worksheet.ChartObjects`, however, [the documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195149.aspx) that it returns a `ChartObjects` collection containing all charts on that sheet.