# Loop over array of a charts

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code that loops over a predefined array of chart names and does smth to every chart
My initial guess was

```
Sub Select_Charts_On_Sheet()
'Selects every chart on a sheet

Dim c As Chart
Dim ChartArray As Variant
ChartArray = Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2", "Chart 3", "Chart 4")
For Each c In Charts(ChartArray)
    MsgBox (c.Name)
Next c

End Sub
```

Yet it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Charts is for Chart Sheets. You can use ChartObjects instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955925/loop-through-all-charts-in-a-workbook-with-vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through all charts in a workbook with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955925/loop-through-all-charts-in-a-workbook-with-vba)

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the worksheet's `ChartObjects`, and check per each `ChartObject.Name` if it's found inside your `ChartArray`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Select_Charts_On_Sheet()
'Selects every chart on a sheet

Dim ChtObj As ChartObject
Dim ChartArray As Variant

ChartArray = Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2", "Chart 3", "Chart 4")

' loop through worksheet's chart objects
For Each ChtObj In Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects ' modify "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
    MsgBox ChtObj.Name

    ' use application match to see if current chart object name is inside the ChartArray (of names)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ChtObj.Name, ChartArray, 0)) Then ' Match was successful
        ChtObj.Select
    End If
Next ChtObj

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To do every chart on a worksheet, it's easy:

```
Dim ChOb As ChartObject
For Each ChOb In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    With ChOb.Chart
        ' do something to each chart
    End With
Next
```

Alternatively:

```
Dim iCht As Long
For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(i).Chart
        ' do something to each chart
    End With
Next
```