# MS Graph Excel list charts in worksheet not working

Tags: excel, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using [this MS graph call](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/worksheet_list_charts) to list the charts in an excel worksheet.

```
GET /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/charts
```

Graph returns this error:

```
{   "error": {
    "code": "GeneralException",
    "message": "There was an internal error while processing the request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "ea42895c-1b98-4d34-baf3-6c544f2ff81c",
      "date": "2018-03-29T04:54:50"
    }   } }
```

I tried different worksheets and chart types with the same result.

It was working until a couple of days ago.

Can anybody reproduce this issue? Is there another way to list the charts in a worksheet?

Note that a similar API call to list the tables in the workbook is working:

```
GET /workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/tables
```

Comment: So is this potentially a problem from MS side? Did you ask in their MS Graph related forums?

Comment: And yes you can loop the chart collection and list charts. Or see the following and adapt Gary's answer to run for a particular sheet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36955925/loop-through-all-charts-in-a-workbook-with-vba

Comment: Any update on this issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: No updates so far here as well.

Comment: Unable to re-produce the issue. Is it happening consistently? What is the HTTP error code that you are receiving?