# Microsoft Graph API and Excel Charts

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-excel

Why Microsoft Graph API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children('GraphTest.xlsx')/workbook/worksheets('Foglio1')/charts
```

throws an error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "GeneralException",
        "message": "There was an internal error while processing the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6b98e61b-2d11-4e16-8a9a-bc9568aeda10",
            "date": "2018-04-14T04:56:21"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure that the file exists and it is correct because this call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children('GraphTest.xlsx')/workbook/worksheets('Foglio1')/names
```

works

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('db444526-887f-48f6-80f9-4e260297921e')/drive/root/children('GraphTest.xlsx')/workbook/worksheets('Foglio1')/names",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": "/users('db444526-887f-48f6-80f9-4e260297921e')/drive/root/children('GraphTest.xlsx')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/names(%27table1%27)",
            "comment": "",
            "name": "table1",
            "scope": "Workbook",
            "type": "Range",
            "value": "Foglio1!$B$2:$C$5",
            "visible": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And the chart exists because if I open the file both on Excel Desktop or Excel Online the chart is there.

And you can see a screenshot of the worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Is this a problem with the service at present? This seems to keep popping up again and again at present. Have you had a look at some of the related questions here? I remember finding something on one of the dedicated Graph forums and posting the link in the comments in a similar question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549502/ms-graph-excel-list-charts-in-worksheet-not-working#comment86106371_49549502 Was where I commented before and there have been a number of similar posts since

Comment: What kind of chart element is on the sheet?

Comment: I've just attached a screenshot of the worksheet

Comment: Any update? I have same problem here

Comment: No one, I'm still waiting for the answer...

Comment: Unable to produce the issue. What is the HTTP error code? Is this happening on all workbooks you are trying with?

Comment: No, sorry, I havn't find any solution. I change company and MS subscription, and I'm not able to access that sheet anymore.