# How to report errors on Microsoft Graph to Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have found more than one error in Microsoft Graph and there seems to be no way to report the errors to Microsoft. On the Graph support site Microsoft gives instructions to request features on user voice, post questions here or report issues on the documentationon github. But there seems to be no way to report issues on the product itself.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Can you give us an example issue that you'd like to report? Also, what do you mean by the 'product'?

Comment: This is an example for an issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549502/ms-graph-excel-list-charts-in-worksheet-not-working. By product I meant the MS Graph API.

Comment: Issues with the Microsoft Graph service API can be opened as [issues against the documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/overview.md). I suggest pointing out how the API doesn't function according to the documentation - please provide a link to the doc in the issue. Issues with the client libraries should be posted in the GitHub repos for the client libraries.